# How to get a variable from the .getJSON function

Tags: javascript, json, function, scope

I want to get the result of the .getJSON function to be accessible from outside the function. Here is my code:

```
var saveResult;
    $.getJSON($query, function(result){
        console.log("Result " +result);
        saveResult = result
        console.log(saveResult)
    });

telemetry = saveResult;
console.log(telemetry);
```

Inside the function, the variable saveResult is printed at the right way in the console. But outside the function, it is printed as undefined.

How can I get the right data outside of the function aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: The problem might be that the getJSON is async. So, by the time it executes, the log is already printed.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async.

Comment: @Eddie is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Basically, when you do `console.log(telemetry);` outside you are printing the `telemetry` before you even receive the data from the backend. That is why you are getting undefined.

Comment: You have to wait for `success` function before you can print the value.

Comment: @Eddie and when does it give success?

Comment: On your callback function. where are you are able to `console.log(saveResult)` successfully.

Comment: This where you can process or call a different function to handle the `saveResult` variable.

Comment: Okay thanks, can you please post an answer/solution to this question? Thanks!

Comment: I cant. This post is marked as duplicate. Nobody can answer to this post. You have to base the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call